# While Creating the CVS(Concurrent Version Control) In Eclipse Error

Tags: android, eclipse, cvs

I am trying to create a CVS repository on my local system. I am doing the tutorial at the following link

http://thedesignspace.net/MT2archives/000661.html

I don't know why this error is coming when I am doing the first part; host, repository path. In repository path I am giving the root folder path, but while creating the repository I am getting the following error. [image: error1]

If I click on Yes and go ahead, Team sharing is giving the following error.[image: error3]

Can anyone please tell me what this error exactly means? Which path do we have to enter in repository path.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What would be the host name and Repository path while Creating the CVS Inside the Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905842/what-would-be-the-host-name-and-repository-path-while-creating-the-cvs-inside-th)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a new repository with Eclipse. The step you are doing is adding a new **repository location** to the repository view in Eclipse, but this will only work if the repository already exists in cvs.

Creating a new repository in cvs should be done using the cvs software itself. How to do this exactly depends on which cvs system you are using.