# What would be the host name and Repository path while Creating the CVS Inside the Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, cvs

I have created a CVS repository on my system. I am using the Eclipse as CVS support already their on the Eclipse I have not imported any new Installation in my Eclipse.

By using [this link](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-92.htm) I am trying to create the repository :

This is what my repo setup looks like:

[image]

When I clicked on the finish, the following error is coming. I don't know whether it is error or Exception. I think I have followed all the steps correctly, yet it is giving the error.

[image]

Comment: Hi Mayur, this may be possible because of your proxy settings in your computer.

Comment: @Lucifer proxy Settings? What should I do for this. Is this any firewall. That I have to disable.

Comment: I'd still recommend you ditch CVS for something else.

Comment: no talk with your network admin & try it without proxy settings, if it works that means you have to do proxy settings in eclipse

Comment: @Lucifer this has got nothing to do with proxy settings.

Comment: but Error Dialogbox Contains ProxyHttp Word..

Comment: @Lucifer doesn't mean it's related to Proxy. The core problem is IOException which is because Eclipse cannot cannect to path mentioned in Host + Repo path

Comment: possible duplicate of [While Creating the CVS(Concurrent Version Control) In Eclipse Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892486/while-creating-the-cvsconcurrent-version-control-in-eclipse-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse help documentation on this topic has first line as: **Prerequisite: A CVS server must already be configured on the host machine to create a valid repository location in the Workbench**

You need to have CVS server configured on your machine (or) server to maintain code repository. Ecpise --> CVS acts as client to access the repository.

Here is link for [eclipse help doc](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-92.htm)

Comment: Sorry Wait I will Edit My Question. Instead of giving the Answer.

Comment: Hi Can you please check once again I have Edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

If the CVS server is installed on your system, then the host should be either `localhost` or the IP address of your system.

The repository path is likely to be location to where your project files are stored.

Comment: I have tried above by closing the Internet connection but still it is not working. @sathya I have tried this by using the localhost and IP address still not done. I have tried on some other system still not working. If it is Proxy Error then I will try on my home pc. But this the Only procedure by using which we can create the repositary.

Comment: where have you installed the CVS server? @mayurrahatekar

Comment: No i have not Installed any CSV server. can we have to Installed any csv server. but in the above link they have mention "Prerequisite: A CVS server must already be configured on the host machine to create a valid repository location in the Workbench." so can we have to create any CSV server. from the link from where I am taking reference their also they have not mention about CSV server  : 1 . http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-92.htm        2.  http://thedesignspace.net/MT2archives/000662.html

Comment: Dude. You cannot work with CVS if you don't have a CVS server. The whole point with CVS is that it's a centralized source code repository, the entire source code is saved on a central server. If you don't want to install a CVS server, you *cannot* use CVS. As I've  mentioned repeatedly, use something like Mercurial. Also note it's **CVS** (Concurrent Versions System) not **CSV** (Comma Separated File). Also, Prerequisite == something that needs to be there before proceeding. link 1 explicitly mentions you have a CVS server installed, link 2 assumes you have one installed.  @mayurrahatekar

Comment: Sorry can you please tell me from where I will get the CVS Server. I have Installed WINCVS on my system. is Their any other exe that I have to install on my system. In morning I have ask the same question after that I have edited.

Comment: @mayurrahatekar http://dotnetbutchering.blogspot.com/2008/03/how-to-set-up-your-own-cvs-server-and.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6813/discussion-between-mayur-rahatekar-and-sathya)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use cvs locally, you don’t have to enable remote login or use ssh at all. I am using OS X 10.8.4 with Eclipse Indigo SR2 and cvs 1.12.13 (which came bundled with Xcode 4.6.3.  cvs is inside the Xcode application bundle. To run it, you always precede the cvs commands with xcrun, as in:

```
$ xcrun cvs -d /path/to/repository init
```

This allows you to configure Eclipse to use xcrun to access all cvs commands instead of using a shell. Open Eclipse preferences and choose Team->CVS->Ext Connection Method and apply the following settings:

```
CVS_RSH:     xcrun
Parameters:  (put white space, cannot be blank)
CVS_SERVER:  cvs
```

Then create a new cvs repository location with the following settings:

```
Host:             localhost
Repository Path:  /absolute/path/to/repository
User:             anything, doesn’t matter, won’t be used
Password:         anything, doesn’t matter, won’t be used
Connection Type:  ext
```

This setup assumes the cvs repository already exists on your local mac. If not, create it by creating a folder for it and then using the following command from terminal:

```
$ xcrun cvs -d /absolute/path/to/repository init
```

Now you are set up and can begin using Eclipse with your local cvs repository.